# unable to cast refs returned from `ChunkedArray::chunks` to concrete arrow type

Tags: apache-arrow, rust-polars

I'm trying to extract the raw buffers from `ChunkedArray`.  The `arrow2` documentation suggests doing this by casting a `&dyn arrow2::array::Array` as its concrete type, see [here](https://jorgecarleitao.github.io/arrow2/main/guide/high_level.html#downcast-and-as_any).

This seems to work fine when I create an arrow buffer directly, however, whenever I try this with the references returned by `ChunkedArray::chunked` the result is a `None`.

I'm not very experienced with rust, so I've been assuming that I was somehow not using the proper reference, however it *really, really* looks like these are the same:

```rust
fn print_type_name<T>(_: T) {
    println!("type: {:?}", std::any::type_name::<T>());
}

fn print_ref_type_name<T: ?Sized>(_: &T) {
    println!("ref type: {:?}", std::any::type_name::<T>());
}

fn from_chunked_wtf() {
    let a: ChunkedArray<Int64Type> = ChunkedArray::from_vec("a", vec![1,2,3]);
    let c1 = a.chunks().first().unwrap();
    // c1 is a ref to a box of a dyn Array, so we deref twice
    // to get the array, then the ref is what we have in working_conversion
    print_ref_type_name(&**c1);
    let b = (&(**c1)).as_any().downcast_ref::<PrimitiveArray<i64>>();
    println!("arrow type: {:?}", &(**c1).data_type().to_physical_type());
    print_type_name(b);
    println!("wtf: {:?}", b);
}

fn working_conversion() {
    let a = PrimitiveArray::<i64>::from_vec(vec![1, 2, 3]);
    let a = &a as &dyn arrow2::array::Array;
    let b = a.as_any().downcast_ref::<PrimitiveArray<i64>>();
    print_ref_type_name(a);
    println!("arrow type: {:?}", a.data_type().to_physical_type());
    print_type_name(b);
    println!("wtf: {:?}", b);
}
```

This prints as:

```
ref type: "dyn arrow2::array::Array"
arrow type: Primitive(Int64)
type: "core::option::Option<&arrow2::array::primitive::PrimitiveArray<i64>>"
wtf: None

ref type: "dyn arrow2::array::Array"
arrow type: Primitive(Int64)
type: "core::option::Option<&arrow2::array::primitive::PrimitiveArray<i64>>"
wtf: Some(Int64[1, 2, 3])
```

Am I doing something wrong here?  Is there some subtle difference between the references in the boxes in `chunked` and the reference I create directly in `working_conversion` that I'm not understanding?

Thanks!

Comment: I tested out your code; both work as expected.  You may have experienced a version of polars that did not downcast correctly.  The None result in your demonstration shows up as `Some(Int64[1, 2, 3])` "in my hands" :))